# Kapustin-Witten branes and the derived moduli stack of Higgs bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-algebraic-geometry, mirror-symmetry, geometric-langlands

A lot has been discussed on overflow regarding geometric Langlands and the physics of Kapustin and Witten's groundbreaking paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0604151. I would like to add my two cents on the topic and ask specifically about the harmonisation two aspects; (1) **Kapustin and Witten's branes** - specifically those of type BBB and BAA, and (2) the role of **derived moduli stacks**. In the original Kapustin-Witten formalism, these branes live on the moduli space of Higgs bundles $\mathcal{M}_G(X)$, where $X$ is a smooth algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ and $G$ is a reductive gorup.

To make contact with the geometric Langlands correspondence, it seems that Kapustin and Witten's branes should live on the derived moduli stack of Higgs bundles;
$$
\operatorname{Higgs}_G(X) = \operatorname{Maps}_{dSt}(X_{Dol}, BG).
$$

**My question:** Do physicists have a way to make branes stacky, so that Kapustin-Witten's branes live on $\operatorname{Higgs}_G(X)$?

My simple-minded thought on this: Kapustin and Witten consider a sigma model with target in $\mathcal{M}_G(X)$, so perhaps I am asking for the construction of a similar sigma model with target $\operatorname{Higgs}_G(X)$.

Gaiotto and Witten (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.01732.pdf) describe the situation as; *The mathematical statement that the correct formulation involves stacks corresponds to the quantum field theory statement that the correct formulation is in four dimensions*. My question is perhaps asking for an explanation of this quotation.

To add a little bit about the mathematical side of things - the Betti geometric Langlands paper of Nadler--Ben-Zvi provides "BAA branes on $\operatorname{Higgs}_G(X)$ $\simeq$ nilpotent sheaves", and the Overflow forum "Geometric Langlands: From D-mod to Fukaya" gives the D-module perspective. BBB branes are "hyperkahler rotations of $D^b(\operatorname{Higgs}_G(X))$", an idea I tried to capture in https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.10032.

I would love to hear perspectives on the mathematical interpretation, but this post is primarily my attempt to understand the original motivation from physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

The sigma model to $M_G(X)$ is a low energy approximation to a 2d gauge theory with gauge group $Maps(X, G)$. Studying the sigma model to the stack $Higg_G(X)$ is basically the same as studying the gauge theory.

This same thing happens when people approximate a 2d GLSM by a sigma model with target given by a GIT quotient. As is well known from toric mirror symmetry this approximation doesn’t always behave well when the quotient isn’t semi-positive.

Comment: Thank you for this! Two questions; (1) do you have a reference where these gauge theories are studied, and (2) are these gauge theories with target in derived stacks, rather than classical 1-stacks?

Comment: These aren’t usually explicitly identified as gauge theories in the physics literature but that coinage literally just means take group invariants in the correct quantum sense on a theory whose fields are maps…

Comment: Also the derived stack structure is built in automatically. It appears as a geometric description of the structure coming from supersymmetry (specifically the choice of square zero supercharge) on the space of fields

Comment: None of this is special to the particular situation in Kapustin Witten - eg the B model of mirror symmetry (constructed eg via gauged linear sigma models) has a built in derived stack structure on the target, except it’s usually “degenerate “ (ie have a classical scheme description)